# Twig Template Unit Testing

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration, twig

I began to think about Continuous Integration for the twig templates in Symfony.

1. A template is independent logic.
2. There are mistakes in the templates.  But in the process of development I do not want to be distracted by visual inspection.

Are there any ready-made solutions for unit testing a twig file in Symfony?

Comment: Can you explicitly say which problems you're referring to? Unit testing a template? and what else?

Comment: I want to implement a full  inspections for templates inspections.
Validation of the templates(errors for syntax, the correct use of extensions). Checking the logic template. For checking logic? I would like to use unit tests. But for maybe use something else for validation, like as lint.

Comment: Twig lint already exists. In symfony2 you can run `php app/console twig:lint <file>`.

Comment: You may want to look into functional tests, where you can test that your get correct output for given input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a [`WebTestCase`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php) (extension of a phpunit `TestCase` since Symfony 2.0) / [`KernelTestCase`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.5/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php) (extension of phpunit `TestCase` since Symfony 2.5)

```
    $twig = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('twig');
    $html = $twig->render('AppBundle::app/something.html.twig', ['content' => 'I am some variable value']);
    self::assertEquals($html, $response->getContent());
```

Answer (score 8):

**Testing for syntax error within twig templates:**

You can use the command line to test on all twig templates into one Bundle by using:

```
php app/console twig:lint @name of Bundle
```

Example:

```
php app/console twig:lint @AcmeDemoBundle
```

The result will be:

if there isn't any syntax error:

```
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/hello.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/contact.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/index.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/layout.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/login.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/helloadmin.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/hello.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Welcome/index.html.twig
```

If there is a syntax error, it will detect line which syntax error in it and reason for Syntax error:

```
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/hello.html.twig
KO in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/contact.html.twig (line 6)
   4      
   5      {% block content %}
>> 6          <form action="{{ ath('_demo_contact') }}" method="POST" id="contact_form">
>> The function "ath" does not exist. Did you mean "path", "logout_path" 
   7              {{ form_errors(form) }}
   8      
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/index.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/layout.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/login.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/helloadmin.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Secured/hello.html.twig
OK in /var/www/SymBlog/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Welcome/index.html.twig
```

Comment: shouldn't such errors be directly displayed by the ide on the fly?

Comment: it depends on the IDE and if you have the syntax check turned ON. For example, I use phpstorm and have to turn the syntax checker off sometimes in huge twig templates because it needs more ram than i have :(

Answer (score 7):

In addition to verifying the structural and syntactical correctness of your Twig template files by linting them, you can also unit test the logic of your Twig templates.

For example, you can verify the correct behaviour of an `if-elseif-else-endif` construct, and you can do so in isolation, that is, without the need to go through controllers with all their dependencies.

Have a look at https://github.com/journeymonitor/control/blob/2645c69/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/testcases/_testresults-overview-testresult-label.html.twig. It's a very simple template, but it does have some amount of behaviour - depending on the value of `testresult.exitCode`, different label names must be output.

At https://github.com/journeymonitor/control/blob/bc42e78/tests/AppBundle/Resources/views/testcases/_testresults-overview-testresult-label.html.twig.test.php, you can see the unit test case for this template.

The test case sets up a new `Twig_Environment`, which enables you to load the Twig template file and `render` it with different `Testresult` objects passed in as a parameter. The result of the render operation can then be asserted as in any other PHPUnit test:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../src/AppBundle/Resources/views/testcases/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/var/tmp/journeymonitor-twig-tests-cache',
));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('_testresults-overview-testresult-label.html.twig');

$testresult = new \AppBundle\Entity\Testresult();
$testresult->setExitCode(0);

$this->assertSame('success', $template->render(['testresult' => $testresult]));
```

Note the shell commands on line 8 and 9 - the Twig environment caches its template files, and in order to have reliable tests, you need to ensure that the cache location is wiped before each test run:

```
`rm -rf /var/tmp/journeymonitor-twig-tests-cache`;
`mkdir -p /var/tmp/journeymonitor-twig-tests-cache`;
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to $twig-addExtension() to get the Symfony routes and extras to parse without an error.  I haven't been able to get it working just yet.  But I think that's the route (no pun intended) I need to go to make it test my twig files.

Answer (score 2):

**Use symfony to test an individual twig file like this:**

```
./app/console twig:lint /yourproject/yourtwigs/views/yourtwig.html.twig
```

Result if OK:

```
OK in /yourproject/yourtwigs/views/yourtwig.html.twig
```

Result if not OK (I added a curly brace where it didn't belong):

```
/yourproject/yourtwigs/views/yourtwig.html.twig (line 2)
   1      {% include 'YourBundle:Includes:jquery.html.twig' %} 
>> 2      {{% include 'YourBundle:Includes:datatables.html.twig' %}
>> Unexpected "}" 
   3      <script>
   4      $(document).ready(function()
```